# Disable clusters in Yandex Maps API

Tags: yandex-maps, yandex-api

I have an Yandex Maps installed on my project

Code below display an cluster view of all objects.
What I would like to do is disable clusters

```
    $.getJSON( ymFormAction , "ymJSON=1" ).done( function (json) {

        window.geoObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(json);

        window.clusters = geoObjects.search("geometry.type == 'Point'").clusterize({preset: 'islands#invertedblueClusterIcons'});
        myMap[[+idMap]].geoObjects.add(clusters);

        // Trying to disable clusters
        var coords = geoObjects;
        // coords should be = [[56.023, 36.988]] according to API

        var myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
        for (var i = 0; i<coords.length; i++) {
            myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords[i]));
        }
        myMap[[+idMap]].geoObjects.add(myCollection);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `ymaps.geoQuery` doesn't return coordinates (or a `GeoObjectCollection` for that matter). What it returns is [`GeoQueryResult`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/). Here what you can do to add results of `geoQuery` to a map:

```
ymaps.geoQuery(json).search("geometry.type == 'Point'").addToMap(yourMap);
```

Comment: This will result an empty map

Comment: I've fixed the answer.